# Do hashmaps needs transaction

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a hashmap in a document. Let's say it looks like:

```
userHasFinished: {
 'user1': false,
 'user2': false,
 'user3': false,
}
```

If I'm updating specific fields in this hashmap from `false` to `true`, and I know that only one user can initiate a write for a particular field (this is guarded by authentication), do I need a transaction for this update?

Put another away, do I need a transaction to make concurrent updates to a hashmap even though those concurrent updates will always be to different keys in the hashmap?

I'm assuming not because inherently an entire Firestore document is essentially a hashmap and you certainly don't need transactions to update individual fields in a document.

Comment: Hey Chris. Did you make any progress on this? I tried helping with an answer below. Did you have a chance to check that out?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use a transaction if the data that you write depends on the current data in the same document.

A user adding their own UID to a map does not require the existing data in the document, so can be safely (and more efficiently) done with a merging `set` or update call, as long as you address the specific subfield with a `.`. For example: `{ "userHasFinished.user1": false }`.

Also see the documentation on [updating fields in nested objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_fields_in_nested_objects), which contains example code for many supported languages.